# How to add 1st array elements to each other array elements using recursive function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

for ex: I have this array

```
arr=[1,3,7,8];
1st call will result in: [4,8,9]
2nd Call will result in:[12,13]
3rd call will result in:[25]

How to do this using recursion in javascript?
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Without any evidence of what you already know, it's pretty difficult to write a high quality answer that addresses what you don't understand. This site isn't just a code-writing service.

Comment: Are you looking for `sum = ([h,...t]) => h && sum(t.map(a => a + h)) || h`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you want to do it recursively, but this is one possible solution -

```
function sum(arr){
  // base case
  if(arr.length === 1 || arr.length === 0) {
    return arr
  } else {
    return sum(arr.slice(1).map(el => el + arr[0]))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 cases to consider

1. when an empty array is provided, return an empty array
2. when an an array of 1 element is provided, return the same array
3. when an array of 2 or more elements is provided, return the tail of the array with each element of the tail added to the head

```js
const foo = ([x,...xs]) => {
  if (x === undefined)
    return []
  else if (xs.length === 0)
    return [x]
  else
    return foo(xs.map(y => x + y))
}

console.log(foo([]))        // []
console.log(foo([1]))       // [1]
console.log(foo([1,3]))     // [4]
console.log(foo([1,3,7]))   // [12]
console.log(foo([1,3,7,8])) // [25]
```

The function could be improved if you separate some of the concerns by writing some helpers

```js
const add = x => y => x + y

const isEmpty = xs => xs.length === 0

const isNull = x => x == null

const foo = ([x,...xs]) => {
  if (isNull(x))
    return []
  else if (isEmpty(xs))
    return [x]
  else
    return foo(xs.map(add(x)))
}

console.log(foo([]))        // []
console.log(foo([1]))       // [1]
console.log(foo([1,3]))     // [4]
console.log(foo([1,3,7]))   // [12]
console.log(foo([1,3,7,8])) // [25]
```